# App Crashes when I click Tab Bar Controller

Tags: ios, ios7, xcode5.1, cs193p

I'm working my way through Stanford's iOS 7 course and I'm stuck at Task 1 on Assignment 4.

I linked two scenes via CTRL + click to a Tab Bar Controller. I'll call them Scene A and Scene B.

If I link Scene A first, the app loads and does what it's supposed to...until I click the tab for Scene B, at which point the app crashes with the following exception:

```
2014-06-25 13:31:12.255 Matchismo[4976:60b] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[NSRegularExpression enumerateMatchesInString:options:range:usingBlock:]: nil argument'
```

If I link Scene B first, the app crashes out of the gate, despite no compiler errors. Both scenes have a view controller set for them. Scene B's view controller is a subclass of Scene A's view controller.

Where should I be looking for the problem?

Comment: Have you tried [debugging your small program](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)?

Comment: what message appears in the console when the app crashes?

Comment: 2014-06-25 13:31:12.255 Matchismo[4976:60b] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[NSRegularExpression enumerateMatchesInString:options:range:usingBlock:]: nil argument'

Comment: Post code from the second view controller or  whereever are you using NSRegularExpression?

Comment: Thank you to those who responded. I was able to solve the problem by going to Window/Organizer in XCode, highlighting the project in the lefthand column of the view, and deleting the derived data.

Answer (score 0):

Always post the error message with your question. Did you google your error? Follow this link,

[NSRegularExpression enumerateMatchesInString:options:range:usingBlock: giving a null result?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10961779/nsregularexpression-enumeratematchesinstringoptionsrangeusingblock-giving-a)

I believe your error is not related to your tab view controller, but what's inside your view B. They're not empty, right?

Comment: I ended up nuking the derived data and the app worked. I'm not sure how or why, but it works. Thank you for answering my rookie question.

Comment: No problem. Nice it worked out. I made that mistake when I posted my first question here, so I thought I pass it on ;)